# Using custom functions to format display of values in plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I am writing a small web-app to display prices over time for certain items in a game. The prices are integers but I want to format them to how the in game currency is displayed. This is the function I am using. It takes an integer and returns a string.

```
def copper_to_price(copper): # Converts copper int to a normal price
copper = int(copper)
s, c = divmod(copper, 100)
g, s = divmod(s, 100)
if g == 0:
    if s == 0:
        return '{}c'.format(c)
    else:
        return '{}s{}c'.format(s, c)
else:
    return '{}g{}s{}c'.format(g, s, c)
```

I am plotting these prices with plotly and want to have the y-axis ticks and y value hover text to be formatted with my function.

With plotly you can specify an y-axis tick formatter using [tickformat](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#scatter-marker-colorbar-tickformat) but it seems you can only specify predefined formatting options and cannot pass your own custom formatting function.

It is also possible to specify your own tick values using [tickvals](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#bar-marker-colorbar-tickvals) and replace the text of these values with [ticktext](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#bar-marker-colorbar-ticktext). I could specify my own y values and then format it with my function and return that as my ticktext but then I would have to generate my own y value ticks that will fit my data. I haven't found any good python scripts that can generate y tick values that will fit your data well.

How can I display my y values formatted with my own function using plotly?

Answer (score 0):

You already described the way to go. Why not take your plotting data, extract minimum and maximum values, use `tv = np.arrange(min, max, 0.25)` to create the sequence of `tickvals` and then use `ticktext = [copper_to_price(member) for member in tv]` to format them. When you are done with that, just set the corresponding layout options

```
layout = go.Layout(
    yaxis=dict(
        tickmode='array',
        tickvals=tv,
        ticktext=tt
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. The problem with the arange function is that it will not give me rounded values which will look messy. I could round the min and max value to fix that but there would be another issue. Some prices are in the range of 10E3 and some 10E6. I want to have 6 yticks that will fit my data. Too many yticks look messy and too little give no info. So I would have to dynamically determine an interval. I am just disappointed that in order to format ytick values in plotly I have make my own function to generate them while the default yticks intervals are perfect already.